# Error on calling constant in Java

Tags: java, android, performance, android-intent, android-asynctask

I'm trying to parse json in my app:

So first I Created constant class for my android app, which has about 6 variables for app.config:

(Class: 1)

```
public class Constants{

    // url to make request
    public static String url = "http://server.com/";

    // JSON Node names
    public static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "contacts";
    public static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    public static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    public static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
    public static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "address";
    public static final String TAG_GENDER = "gender";

}
```

now I want to use this in different class so I went ahead and created different class:

(Class: 2)

```
    public class ReadFiles{

        public void readConstant(){
       //appConfig is JSONArray
        JSONArray appConfig = null;
       // Creating JSON Parser instance
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();


        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(c.url);

        try {
            // Getting Array of Contacts
            contacts = json.getJSONArray(Constants.TAG_CONTACTS);

            // looping through All Contacts
            for(int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++){
                JSONObject d = details.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing each json item in variable  
                String id = d.getString(Constants.TAG_ID); //Error: 
        //ERROR :  The method getString(int) in the type  JSONArray is not applicable for the arguments-(String)
                String name = d.getString(Constants.TAG_NAME);
                String email = d.getString(Constants.TAG_EMAIL);
                String address = d.getString(Constants.TAG_ADDRESS);
                String gender = d.getString(Constants.TAG_GENDER);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

I'm getting error on block : `String name = c.getString(Constants.TAG_NAME);`
 where I'm trying apply constant values to local variable by parsing json.

I followed eclipse tips and did also try to do

```
String name = c.(Constants.TAG_NAME);
```

But still no luck. What is wrong in this block? How can I assign json values to local variables? 
For your knowledge : this is what I'm trying to achieve: [android-json-parsing-tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) 
But I want to keep the constant in separate class.

Updated: So i made changes that you have suggested and i get new error:
`String tabTitle = appConfig.(ConfigConstants.TITLE);  //Error: Syntax error on token ".", Identifier expected after this  token`

Comment: You are trying to access static members through class instance, You should access the static members with Class Name.

Comment: check my answer update, for your update + Clean up your code and paste the code where `tabTitle` is used. Current question has nothing related to that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not simply use this?

```
Constants.TAG_NAME
```

Why instantiate your `Constants` class? Since, all the fields in the `Constants` class `static`, they need to be accessed in a `static` way only (i.e.) by using the `ClassName`(**Constants**).

**Update:-**

```
appConfig.(ConfigConstants.TITLE);
```

Shouldn't there be a method? Something like this.

```
appConfig.someMethodName(ConfigConstants.TITLE);
```

Comment: Hi, I made changes and did : `String tabTitle = appConfig.getString(ConfigConstants.TITLE);` but still getting error.

Comment: This is 1 weird code. `for(int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++){
            JSONObject d = details.getJSONObject(i);`

Comment: `d` is a `JSONObject`, which does take a `String` for the `getString()` method.

Comment: Is there any method that i can replace getString (int), since i have appConfig.someMethodName(String);?

Comment: what type of object is `appConfig`? And can you post that code snippet too. It'll help in better understanding

Comment: appConfig is JSONArray
        `JSONArray appConfig = null;`   i have updated in above-code, Thanks mate!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26846/discussion-between-r-j-and-dixit)

Answer (score 0):

i guess you are using JSONArray class in the package

```
org.json.JSONArray
```

which has a method

```
getString(int)
```

given this method accepts an integer parameter, if you pass a string argument, it is obvious to throw an error by Eclipse

Comment: mmm yup you right, so how can i joint    `String tabTitle = appConfig.(ConfigConstants.TITLE);`
which means jointing three variables into one variables

Comment: use "contacts" instead of Constants.TAG_CONTACTS and likewise for others. just try :)